# Displaying $0.00 for DBNull value with DataFormatString

Tags: asp.net, string-formatting, detailsview

I'm using DataFormatString to convert a price boundfield into a currency format by using DataFormatString="{0:c}" for my detailsview.

However, it seems like if the value is blank or null from the database, instead of just displaying blank on my details view, the DataFormatString makes it show up as $0.00. I tried to set the NullDisplayText="" but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas how to do this? Do I need to use a ItemTemplate instead?

This is how I get the data in the .aspx

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Price] FROM [DataBase] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)">
```

This is the code that binds the data:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price:" SortExpression="Price" 
            DataFormatString="{0:c}" NullDisplayText="" />
```

Comment: How are you getting the data? Can you not use a stored procedure that will return `0` if the value  is empty or null?

Comment: Updated my question showing where I get the data

Comment: Looks like a better query could help (take a look at [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx)).

Comment: Could you add the asp code where you bind the received value?

Comment: Updated the question with the asp code

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in the codebehind - consider looking up and using the Databind event for your datagrid to make this easier:

```
If (value is DBNull) return "" else return FormattedValue(value)
```

That may not be exactly what you want but it does exactly what you want; you just need to use the ItemDataBound Event of your DataGrid to use that. Return non null value however you want; I used FormattedValue for clarity.